# Reimplement HTML Media Tag Fetching without a tag using Media Source API

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, video-player, media-source

I am trying to re implement the fetching stack of a video tag before the tag is mounted.

Media Source API seems to be the right solution to do this, but it does not seems to open if I don't attach it to a media tag. (not receiving the `sourceopen` event).

My requirement are that I can :

- Open one or multiple source and fill them as I want using partial fetching on my video(s) (that I control).
- I can as I go attach and detach the Sources to a video player.

Is it possible to do this with Media Source ?

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: The fetching of content is independent from how you use it in MediaSource.  You can certainly go and pre-fetch whatever you want using whatever API you want, independent from media altogether.

Comment: @Brad you are right, maybe I asked my question poorly : How can I prefetch the video, play it before it has ended to fetch, unattach it and re-attach it whenever I want, and so on...

But this makes me thinks, I may indeed not need to create a media source from the beginning, I could just use a buffer in advance and create the media feed when I need. 

Thanks for the answer I will look into this solution.